# How does Google feel about overflow: auto?

Tags: seo, google, googlebot

I am planning to add some keyword rich text to my homepage at the very top. I have written almost a mini essay and putting all this text at the very top left of my page wouldn't look too nice. I was wondering if putting it inside a 500 X 200 div and using overflow: auto on it would help or get me penalized?

e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/svaXY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't make any difference on your rankings at all. You're not doing anything to manipulate the rankings which is what matters.

Comment: I read that google penalizes for hidden content so if instead of overflow: auto I had used display: none or even overflow: hidden. I think overflow: auto is definitely a gray area at best. If it doesn't harm then it will be great though.

Comment: It's not a grey area at all. As long as you're serving the same content to the search engines as your users and you're not trying to manipulate your rankings you're fine.

Comment: I agree with John, I don't think this is a grey area at all. Overflow:auto is just telling the browser to show a scroll bar if the contents cannot fit inside the specified area. Why would Google penalize you for doing this?

Comment: That's good to know. I just thought if for example someone gave a div the height of 1 px and filled it with seo text and gave it overflow auto then it could be seen as the same as hiding text. I am not giving it 1px height, just saying.